# Error in request sent to appengine backend devserver

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a bunch of code which would run on backend but when testing locally I am getting memcache related error

```
INFO   : { AppEngineUserRealm isUserInRole          } - Checking if principal test@example.com is in role admin 
SEVERE : { ShardedMemcacheUtil get                  } - Error encountered while getting [ configuration ] from memcache. 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.StatsProtos$RequestStatProto$Builder cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.StatsProtos$RequestStatProto$Builder
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.MemcacheWriter.write(MemcacheWriter.java:210)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recorder.processRecordingFuture(Recorder.java:456)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recorder.processAsyncRpc(Recorder.java:404)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.RecordingFuture.maybeRecordStats(RecordingFuture.java:140)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.RecordingFuture.get(RecordingFuture.java:110)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.RecordingFuture.get(RecordingFuture.java:20)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.get(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:49)
```

The request was sent to the following URL so that the code is executed in backend.

```
http://localhost:52843/
```

The above request runs fine when sent to

```
http://localhost:8888/
```

Which is actually devserver.

Any clue what's wrong with it when run inside backend ? Also why there are two ports opened for backend **58251** and **58252**

```
INFO   : { JettyLogger info                         } - Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888 
INFO   : { AbstractModule startup                   } - Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8888/ 
INFO   : { AbstractModule startup                   } - The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin 
INFO   : { JettyLogger info                         } - jetty-6.1.x 
INFO   : { ApiProxyLocalImpl log                    } - javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' 

INFO   : { JettyLogger info                         } - Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:58251 
INFO   : { ServerWrapper startup                    } - server: -1.backend1 is running on port 58251 
INFO   : { JettyLogger info                         } - jetty-6.1.x 
INFO   : { ApiProxyLocalImpl log                    } - javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' 

INFO   : { JettyLogger info                         } - Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:58252 
INFO   : { ServerWrapper startup                    } - server: 0.backend1 is running on port 58252 
INFO   : { DevAppServerImpl doStart                 } - Dev App Server is now running
```

**UPDATE** Looks like it was happening because I compiles with Jdk8. I came to know only after I deployed to cloud and it gave me version error. Still not sure why only backend was effected locally.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AlvinBunk added the question explicitly in the last line.

Comment: Just so that everyone knows - clean project worked - not sure what was the problem.